# Setting custom cookies in firefox and chrome?

Tags: firefox, browser, cookies, google-chrome

Is there a way to add a cookie in these? Like "debug=true" and that way my website can test for that?

I'm meaning to be able to use the ui of the browser.

Maybe a plugin/extension?

Basically, I want to be able to test certain features without anyone else seeing them.

Comment: I still haven't found a decent extension in Chrome. There is Edit This Cookie but it lacks the ability to set domain cookies, which is critical to what I need. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In firefox there is the "Web Developer" plugin. It allows you to add arbitrary cookies among MANY other things that are great for web development.

Once installed, go to the cookie menu-> add cookie and fill in the information.

[image]

Comment: Is it safe ? I mean we're storing our private cookies over there ?

Comment: @Amogam It's safe in the sense that your browser has access to all your cookies anyway (how else would it be able to send those?), so you need to trust your browser.